# Composer: class not found, cannot find where I am wrong

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a php project.

This is the composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "bcosca/fatfree": "3.6.4",
        "sineverba/domoticz-api": "^1.0",
        "sineverba/supportdate":"dev-v1.0.0-alpha"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@github.com:sineverba/supportdate.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

`sineverba\domotic-api` is published on packagist. `sineverba\supportdate` no (started tonight).

In a file `Script.php` under `app/models` folder

`app
    | models
        Script.php`

I require my 2 libraries (domoticz-api and supportdate)

I have

```
<?php

/**
 * Main script class
 * 
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

namespace models;
use \sineverba\domoticzapi as Api;
use \sineverba\supportdate as Supportdate;

class Script() {

    //some property here

    public function __construct() {

        $api = new Api\Client( $this->_user,$this->_password,$this->_host );
        $date = new Supportdate\SupportDate();

    }
}
```

$api object is created correctly. $date I get the error `Class 'sineverba\supportdate\SupportDate' not found`

I did try also:

- Remove the declaration `use \sineverba\supportdate as Supportdate;`
- Call directly `$date = new \sineverba\supportdate\SupportDate()`

As said, `$api` (object of sineverba\domoticz-api, that is published on packagist) is instantiated correctly, so autoload mode of Fat Free Framework (the framework that I use) is working correctly.

You can also see that `domoticz-api` and `supportdate` are very similar also in composer.json.

In my webserver the folders for both libraries are correctly present under /vendor/sineverba/domoticz-api and /vendor/sineverba/supportdate

I did try also creating an index.php inside my `supportdate` library

```
<?php

require("vendor/autoload");

$date = new \sineverba\supportdate\SupportDate();
```

And it works.

So, we can exclude a library / composer error and a F3 framework error ('cause API is called and instantiated).

Thank you for your support

Comment: In the file where it does not work, try deleting the line and carefully retyping it. Sometimes I inadvertently add unprintable characters when typing fast, and the symptoms fit: (a) one, but not another similar class works, which rules out `composer dump-autoload` and (b) it works when typed in another file.

Comment: gawrsh..... @bishop ..... Don't know what done, retyping as 1 letter by 1 letter solved..... 1 hour trashed. Thank you..... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I inadvertently add unprintable characters when typing fast. The symptoms you're experiencing fit:

1. one, but not another similar class works, which rules out composer dump-autoload
2. it works when typed in another file.

Deleting the line, then retyping slowly forces your mind to dump prior assumptions and start from scratch. This can be helpful if there are issues of unprintable characters, case differences, or any other oddities that sometimes we're blind to in the midst of development.